# Program fails at syntax command

Tags: stata

Below is a simple dataset based on what I'm working with, followed by a program I wrote. It is just supposed to quickly tell me when one of my data collection teams was at a particular school, and I can ask for the school by name or code.

```
clear
input float(date group school_code) str15 school
1 1 23 "Lincoln HS"
2 1 21 "Washington HS"
3 1 32 "Clay HS"
1 2 54 "Adams HS"
2 2 11 "Jackson HS"
3 2 15 "Monroe HS"
1 3 27 "Rosevelt HS"
2 3 49 "Grant HS"
3 3  3 "Kennedy HS"
end
```

Small warning, this program uses the `groups` command which can be found on SSC.

```
program define WhenWas
syntax, Group(int) [ School(str) Code(int) ]
version 16
if "`school'" != "" groups date school school_code group if school == "`school'" & group == `group', sepby(date) missing show(freq)
if `code' != . groups date school school_code group if school_code == `code' & group == `group', sepby(date) missing show(freq)
end
```

But when I run the command to use the program, I get an "Invalid Syntax" error at the syntax line of the program, seemingly before it even begins to go into the commands.

```
WhenWas, g(2) c(54)
```

I've tried capitalizing the words in the syntax line, using the full words in the `WhenWas`command, etc.

Comment: The provenance of `groups` is best cited as from the _Stata Journal_.  `search st0496, entry` is the best way to find code and discussion.

Answer (score 1):

In your program that doesn't work, the problem lies within

```
syntax, Group(int) [ School(str) Code(int) ]
```

As `code()` is an optional option that expects an integer, it must have a specified default. If you don't want to specify a default, then

```
syntax, Group(int) [ School(str) Code(numlist int max=1) ]
```

is a way not to do that. but you need to check that a code was specified:

```
if "`code'" == "" { 
     di as err "code() not specified" 
     exit 198 
}
```

as otherwise your next command referring to `code` will fail. See the `help` for `syntax` for more details.

An alternative is to specify a nonsense code as default, which might be `-1` if codes are all positive.